# How to specify URL parameter on a OWASP Zap (GUI) automated attack

Tags: owasp, zap

I'm using the OpenAPI support plugin to crawl a REST API routes (/v1/*/* on HTTP vebs) and run an automated scan.
How can I specify and test the URL parameters of the API ? (limit, offset, pagesize, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Proxy manual use/exercise of the API.
- Proxy some automated functional tests of the API.

Then run an automated scan on the API use (verbs/params) that ZAP is now aware of.

Edit: 2020-04-22 > There is also currently an open PR which adds support for "example" param values in your OpenAPI definition.